# Empty dictionary request.FILES when image posted from Android

Tags: android, python, django, retrofit

I am trying to make an Android application that would post the taken photo to django server using Retrofit framework.

My android part:

```
private void uploadFile(Uri filePath) {

        String path = getRealPathFromURI(filePath);

        File originalFile = new File(String.valueOf(path));

        RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),originalFile);

        MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", path, filePart);

        ApiRequestsService.UploadFile(this, new OnApiResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onApiComplete(Object object) {
                RetrofitResponse response = (RetrofitResponse) object;
                Toast.makeText(context, response.success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onApiError(Exception e) {
            }
        }, "Loading...", file);
    }

@Multipart
@POST("/uploadImage/")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(@Part("upload") MultipartBody.Part file);
```

In the views.py file on the server side I have:

```
def uploadImage(request):
    # check to see if this is a post request
    if request.method == "POST":

        print request.FILES
        if 'upload' in request.FILES: 
            print "success!"
            upload = request.FILES['upload']
        else:
            print "something's wrong"
```

The response I get is:

```
[14/Jan/2018 15:55:24] "POST /uploadImage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 47
MultiValueDict: {}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please stop using Python 2.7,

Comment: @zmbq that doesn't really answer the question, for this project I need Python 2.7.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment.